# copy/map json/data class structure in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, data-class

I am newbie in kotlin and I try to copy a JSON structure to another one in an efficient way.

I have an API called getData() how send back a data structure defined as below:

```
data class DataA(
    var id: String,
    var cartItems: List<CartItem>, 
}
```

When the getData sent back the DataA structure, I have to map or translate it to another structure defined as below:

```
data class DataB(
    var cartItems: List<CartItem>, 
}
```

Is there an easy way to do it? I know that kotlin can easily encapsulate calls to make it nice.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to simply convert `DataA` to `DataB` or you need to create a `DataB` instance that contains a clone of `cartItems` list?

Comment: I need an instance of DataB.

Answer (score 0):

Since you simply need to convert an instance of `DataA` to an instance of `DataB`, what you can do is `DataB(dataA.cartItems)`, where `dataA` is the instance of `DataA`.

Note, however, that if for any reason you modify any item of `cartItems` from `dataA`, this change will be reflected also to `dataB`, since they share the same list object.